# Python - LMDB has no attribute open

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe, lmdb

I'm traying to use lmbd in python.

The thing is that i get the same error when the code is running

**In this line : `env = lmdb.open('/latas/nuevo.lmdb', map_size=map_size)`**

But that only happens when I run the code from a file, when I typed the code through the python prompt there is no issue.

```
  File "C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\lmdb.py", line 20, in <module>
    env = lmdb.open('latas', max_dbs = 10)

AttributeError: module 'lmdb' has no attribute 'open'
```

Any idea of what's happening there?

Thank you.

Comment: please post your full code

Comment: Quite often this kind of issues come from another module by the same name that happens to be first in `sys.path` when you execute your script. You can check this by adding a `print(lmdb)` just after you import it, this will tell you which exact module has been imported under that name.

Comment: I tried to print as you sugested and got another error  `import lmdb
ImportError: bad magic number in 'lmdb': b'\x03\xf3\r\n' `

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

From your console trace:

```
  File "C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\lmdb.py", line 20, in <module>
    env = lmdb.open('latas', max_dbs = 10)

AttributeError: module 'lmdb' has no attribute 'open'
```

I guess you are using lmdb as one of your personal module names and thus it is conflicting with the standard lmdb module.

Comment: I changed the name of my module to `create_lmdb.py` but the issue remains.

Comment: what is the console output now?

Comment: The same. `File "C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\create_lmdb.py", line 20, in <module>
    env = lmdb.open('latas', max_dbs = 10)

AttributeError: module 'lmdb' has no attribute 'open'`

Comment: I guess then you would have to provide the full source.